# What happens to the lock in the following situation, when cond is true?

Tags: c++, thread-safety, mutex, locks

I have this code ,now can anyone reply s what happens to the lock in the following situation considering that cond is true:-

```
for (;;) {
static mutex m;
Lock lock(m);
if (cond)
break;
... 
}
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming `Lock` class follows [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization) principle, it will unlock the mutex.

Comment: Does it unlock the mutex automatically?

Comment: Yes, that is the point of RAII.  It should unlock it in the destructor of Lock, which will be called when the scope is unwound (you exit the for loop).

Answer (score 0):

The RAII allows to unlock the mutex at the end of the scope.

here is another example [Scooped Lock](http://developer-resource.blogspot.fr/2009/01/boost-scoped-lock.html)